# how to get the dimension of two dimension GlobalVariable array zeroinitializer in LLVM .ll

Tags: llvm-ir

I am writing a LLVM pass to read the global variables from .ll, I found one problem to get the dimension of the array that initialaized by zeor, for example:

```
@b = common local_unnamed_addr global [5 x [10 x i32]] zeroinitializer, align 16
```

In this example, I want to get the dimensions 5 and 10.
For the first dimension 5 I can get it but the second 10 I canoot. My code look like:

```
  virtual bool runOnModule(Module &M) 
   { 
    for (auto gv_iter = M.global_begin();gv_iter != M.global_end(); gv_iter++) 
     {
      GlobalVariable *gv = &*gv_iter;
      Constant *const_gv = gv->getInitializer();
       if (const_gv->isNullValue())
        {
         ConstantArray *constArrayd = cast<ConstantArray>(const_gv) ;
         int firstdim = datafile << constArraydd->getType()->getNumElements(); 
         int seconddim = ?????
        }
      }
   }
```

Any idea please??

Comment: `constArraydd->getType()->getElementType()->getArrayNumElements()` ??